# Check if Series has many bad outcomes one after another

Tags: python, pandas

I have many Series like this:

```
0   0.1
1   -0.1
2   -0.2
3   0.14
4   0.17
5   -0.34
6   -0.78
7   -0.22
8   -0.9
9   -0.01
10  0.12
11  0.13
12  0.22
13  -0.24
14  -0.44
15  -0.91
```

I want to check if there are 5 or more negative rows one after another. So for this Series expected output:

```
True
```

Otherwise, in this Series there are no 5 negative rows one after another.

```
0   0.14
1   0.15
2   -0.24
3   0.11
4   0.17
5   0.31
6   -0.79
7   0.22
8   -0.91
9   0.11
10  0.22
11  0.34
12  0.12
13  -0.44
14  -0.14
15  0.31
```

Expected output:

```
False
```

I know how to iterate through the Series. It can be done with iteration.
But I need high speed of pandas to do it very quickly. My Series are very large. May be there is a method under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rolling` and `sum`, together with the check for anything larger or equal to 5.

```
import pandas as pd    

s = pd.Series([0.1,-0.1,-0.2,0.14,0.17,-0.34,-0.78,-0.22,-0.9,-0.01,0.12,0.13,0.22,-0.24,-0.44,-0.91])

((s < 0).rolling(5).sum() >= 5).any()
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

try this masking and summing :) :

```
sr = ... #your data Series
bool_sr = sr < 0
has_5 = ((bool_sr == True) & (bool_sr.shift(1) ==True)).sum() >= 5
```

Comment: Oh i probably didnt got it that you want thwm in a row... ill fix it in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
def is_n_negative_sequence(x, N=5):
    dif = np.diff(x >= 0)
    dif = np.hstack((True, dif, True))
    loc = np.where(dif)
    return bool(np.any(np.diff(loc) >= N))

assert is_n_negative_sequence(np.array([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0])) is True  # left case
assert is_n_negative_sequence(np.array([5,-4,-3,-2,-1,-1, 0])) is True # middle case
assert is_n_negative_sequence(np.array([5,-4,-3,-2,-1, -1])) is True  # right case
assert is_n_negative_sequence(np.array([5,-4,-3,-2,-1, 0])) is False # False case
```